# Apache RewriteRule in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

I have an URL **http://10.20.109.99:10034/a/b/c/d/index.html** hosted in Apache Server. I would like to use RewriteRule to shorten the URL to **http://10.20.109.99:10034/d/index.html** by ignoring the a/b/c. I tried the rule:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^http://10.20.109.99:10034/d/index.html$ http://10.20.109.99:10034/a/b/c/d/index.html [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

and it works when I key in the shortened URL in the browser address bar, however, in the address bar, the URL will change back to the long URL after the redirect and subsequently, when I click on other menu link URL like http://10.20.109.99:10034/a/b/c/d/FAQ.html, the long URL will appear back in the address bar.

The thing I want to archive is when ever I do anything like key in URL address or click on other menu URL (within same **d** folder), the URL in the address bar will always show the shorten one http://10.20.109.99:10034/d/[the_pages].html instead of going back to the long URL.

Thanks.

Comment: `[R]` means redirect. Lose the `R` and just use `[L]`

Answer (score 1):

The use you are doing of RewriteRule is incorrect.

Pattern to match according to documentation is a URL-Path which is the "path" after scheme and hostname.

Also, the target is in the same virtualhost and you don't want the URL to "change", so the redirection is internal, not external as with R flag like Rob has stated.

So basically to internally redirect /d/index.html to the destination you mention you would want this (defined in Virtual Host context):

```
RewriteRule ^/d/index.html$ /a/b/c/d/index.html  [L]
```

And then apply the same method to any other internal redirections you want to make.

References:
[RewriteRule docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)
[Rewrite Flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)
[Context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context)